# My Flutter PopScope is not working anymore

Tags: flutter, dart

I put in a PopScope for one of the pages in my flutter app so that users cannot navigate back to the previous screen when they are on this screen. It worked before, I made some other changes but nothing related to PopScope, so I'm a bit lost as to how this could have happened. The page will still allow a user to navigate back to the previous screen if they tap "Back" on the device.

```
class LoginScreenColor extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreenColor({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xfff51957),
        textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
          cursorColor: Color(0xfff51957),
        ),
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(
                0xfff51957),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xfff51957)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  // Email and Pass focusNodes
  final FocusNode emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();

  // Controllers for Email and Pass
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  // Continue with Google
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
        await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    final UserCredential userCredential =
        await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    // Set a flag to indicate the user has just signed in
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool('justSignedIn', true);

    return userCredential;
  }

  // Sign in with Email and Password
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithEmail() async {
    final String email = emailController.text;
    final String password = passwordController.text;

    final UserCredential userCredential =
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    return userCredential;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) => showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: const Text(
              'Please Complete Setup',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              ),
            ),
            content: const Text(
              'Please complete the setup process first, any and all settings can be changed after initial setup.',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                child: const Text(
                  'Ok',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xfff51957),
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      child: Lottie.asset('assets/sign.json'),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'Discover your next ',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 24.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'adventure',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 24.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: const Color(0xfff51957),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                    TextField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      focusNode: emailFocusNode,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: emailFocusNode.hasFocus
                              ? const Color(0xfff51957)
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    TextField(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      focusNode: passwordFocusNode,
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: passwordFocusNode.hasFocus
                              ? const Color(0xfff51957)
                              : null,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40.0,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          try {
                            await signInWithEmail();
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              PageRouteBuilder(
                                pageBuilder:
                                    (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                                        const PreferencesScreen(),
                                transitionsBuilder: (context, animation,
                                    secondaryAnimation, child) {
                                  var begin = const Offset(1.0, 0.0);
                                  var end = Offset.zero;
                                  var curve = Curves.ease;

                                  var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end)
                                      .chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

                                  return SlideTransition(
                                    position: animation.drive(tween),
                                    child: child,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                            // Handle error
                            print(e.message);
                          }
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff51957),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Sign in',
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                      child: OutlinedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          // Handle Google sign-in
                          final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
                              await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
                          if (googleUser != null) {
                            final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
                                await googleUser.authentication;
                            final OAuthCredential credential =
                                GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                              accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
                              idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
                            );
                            try {
                              final UserCredential userCredential =
                                  await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                              // Check if sign-in was successful
                              if (userCredential.user != null) {
                                // Navigate to PreferencesScreen
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const PreferencesScreen()),
                                );
                              }
                            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                              // Handle error
                              print(e.message);
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        icon: Image.asset('images/google_logo.png',
                            width: 24.0, height: 24.0),
                        label: const Text('Continue with Google'),
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                      child: OutlinedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Handle Apple sign-in
                        },
                        icon: Image.asset('images/apple.png',
                            width: 40.0, height: 40.0),
                        label: const Text('Continue with Apple'),
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0), // Add this line
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Divider(color: Colors.black),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Don\'t have an account? ',
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const RegisterScreenColor(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'Register',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried changing the code like below by adding async, but nothing changed

```
return PopScope(
  canPop: false, // Prevent user from navigating back
  onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: const Text(
            'Please Complete Setup',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            ),
          ),
          content: const Text(
            'Please complete the setup process first, any and all settings can be changed after initial setup.',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: const Text(
                'Ok',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xfff51957),
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    // ...
```

Comment: Change `canPop: false` to `canPop: true.` When `canPop` is `false`, any returns will not take effect.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Chihiro, before when my PopScope was working it was set to false, and worked as it should. Also, according to this library on flutter classes, setting canPop to false should not allow the user to go back (which is what I want): https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short-Answer:**

PopScope does not work if you replace the class it is in with a MaterialApp class and then set the class that the `PopScope` is in as the `home:` attribute.

**Example of where PopScope would NOT work:**

```
class LoginScreenColor extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreenColor({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // ...
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) => showDialog<void>(
        // ...
      child: Scaffold(
```

**Solution/Reason:**

I found the issue and fixed it. Excuse any wrong terminology used, I'm still very new to Flutter and Dart. My LoginScreen class did not have a MaterialApp in its main widget tree, it stemmed from my previous WelcomeScreen's MaterialApp. But I tried making a MaterialApp for my LoginScreen so that I could set a specific theme for it's fields. Meaning I called `LoginScreenColor` class which then as I understood called the LoginScreen class, and somehow that caused the PopScope widget not to work anymore, I left all PopScope code unchanged, removed the LoginScreenColor class, and added my Theme I wanted to add to my previous WelcomeScreen's MaterialApp.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has deprecated WillPopScope and instead suggests that the new widget is used instead:

```
'WillPopScope.new' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use PopScope instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.12.0-1.0.pre.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
```

The replacement is `PopScope` which uses a completely different API. It's a pain to migrate but it's an Android thing so Flutter is stuck having to change how it works:
[Here is the migration guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back)

Comment: I am using PopScope, and my current implementation did work, I'm not sure what I changed for it to not work anymore but I made no changes to the PopScope code.